# How do I uninstall Ubuntu from my laptop?

Tags: lubuntu

How to remove ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with windows 7 ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Turn on the computer.
2. Wait for the HP logo to show.
3. Keep tapping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until you see this screen:

[image: Grub with Windows]

4. Use the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> keys on your keyboard (no mouse!) to navigate to Windows and you should be back up and running!

If your screen **does not** contain an entry for Windows, we're sorry to say but after 2 months, all your files will be lost. The only thing you can do is take the Windows Recovery Environment from the same menu **which will wipe your entire PC**. If you also have no recovery environment in the menu, please restore your PC with the HP Recovery DVD and then your file back-up.

If you also have no HP Recovery DVD, contact HP, they will be able to send you one (this is probably a payable service)

### Alternatively

You can use [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) to reset the Ubuntu password, which would give you access to Ubuntu itself.

Comment: How would he delete Ubuntu once he is inside Windows?

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste: she wants to get inside the Windows that was installed on the PC before the ex-BF took it as that is what I understand from the text, not the title, so that is her major concern...  Once she has access to that, she will: 1/ or be happy, or 2/ drop a comment to get rid of Ubuntu.  That question will then be forwarded to SuperUser.COM.  This question should be flagged as "off-topic" and it will, but in the mean time, she has something to try.  If you disagree with my assessment, feel free to downvote my answer and propose another one. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP G62 and I've reinstalled Windows 7 once. I made backup DVDs.....they didn't work. I downloaded Win 7 from Microsoft. I don't know the exact location but try this : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/where-can-i-download-windows-7-iso-i-have-a/7d964b05-2be9-4800-bc7f-3ca30356fc3d or try searching on the Microsoft site for Windows 7 download. They usually call it a "Digital River" server.

So I burned it to a DVD and installed it fine, and validated it using the number on the license key sticker on the back of the PC. The advantage is that you don't get all the crapware installed that came with your PC. No trialware, etc. It runs fine.

Since then I've learned to use Linux Mint and haven't used Windows in maybe a year. I sure hope you give Ubuntu a try, because it's a better operating system and much safer.

Comment: In addition to the product key, there's a number on the sticker that looks like X15-12345 or similar to that. Try to match this number to the win iso that is downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

Ouch, that sucks.

There are a few ways to do this, the "best" (almost certainly will work):

Boot your computer

Press Esc

What do you see? If you see an option that says "Windows" or "Windows 7" or something like that, use the down arrow to move so that that choice is highlighted.

If the above doesn't work, you may need to boot into your BIOS setup program. Instead of pressing Esc, you may need to press one of the function keys (I think yours may be f10 based on the model).